# Firebase - Get Facebook profile photo URL from uid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When signing in with Facebook in Firebase, I get a user id that's different than general Facebook user ids (as in digits only). Firebase has generated a completely app-unique id which makes it impossible for me to find the profile photo url.

The profileImageURL that is delivered upon Firebase authentication has expired and since these URL's can expire, I cannot save such information to the Firebase database for other users to access. Say if a certain user doesn't reauthenticate him/herself for a while, making this profileImageURL expire, other users cannot see the profile photo unless the user signs in again. What if the user has been inactive for years? Is there no alternative way to fetch the profile photo?

Comment: Once the user has authenticated, the current user is retrieved with (Swift) let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser. Once you have the user variable, you can access their email (let email = user?.email) and their photoURL (let photoURL = user?.photoURL).  Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: @Jay - Like I said, when I access the user?.photoURL, the link has expired. Some people say that it should refresh once you sign in again, but it doesn't. However, even if it would work, the latest link retrieved by the user after signing in will eventually expire as well. This means that if that user gets inactive (long term period), other users won't have access to a working profileURL since the user hasn't refreshed the link yet.

Comment: Maybe one of the Firebaser's can correct me, but the url is the url. It doesn't expire as it's tied to the Firebase uid that's created. That's what allows a user to authenticate with any number of providers and have that user profile data remain the same.

Comment: @Jay - I found the solution actually. I posted it as the correct answer to this question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good! It ties directly back to my comment *it's tied to the Firebase uid that's created*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It does exist in the Firebase documentation:

```
id<FIRUserInfo> userInfo = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.providerData[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [userInfo providerID];
// Provider-specific UID
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [userInfo uid];
```

`[userInfo uid]` is the actual Facebook ID of the user. This is what I can use to fetch an up-to-date photo URL.